# Amplitude for $q\bar{q} \to Z$

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

In ELectroweak theory, the amplitude for the incoming quark and anti quark to $Z$ boson production in the following diagram is given zero. The outgoing particle $Z$ is given here as blue boson.
[image]

I am confused what is the reason behind it.
One reason maybe the $Tr(T^a)$ which is connected with the external particle may give zero, but here the color factor seems to be $T^aT^b\delta^{ab}$, so this is not possible.

Comment: Look at the triangle loop: a color octet and two colorless Z's go into it!

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Write down the amplitude: you will see that a colored object enters the triangle and doesn't leave. So its trace vanishes.